# UnrecognizedPropertyException Unrecognized field "resourceType"?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Hi I want store my JSON object in the store, for which I want to `readValue` using `Jackson mapper` but when running the program its throws

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "resourceType" (Class io.github.semr.proflr.api.entity.Profile), not marked as ignorable
at [Source: java.io.FileInputStream@46ef0a4f; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: io.github.semr.proflr.api.entity.Profile["resourceType"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1909)
at io.github.semr.proflr.impl.ProfileImpl.add(ProfileImpl.java:41)
at io.github.semr.proflr.impl.ProfileImpl.start(ProfileImpl.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.felix.dm.InvocationUtil.invokeMethod(InvocationUtil.java:111)
at org.apache.felix.dm.InvocationUtil.invokeCallbackMethod(InvocationUtil.java:66)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.invokeCallbackMethod(ComponentImpl.java:688)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.invoke(ComponentImpl.java:679)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.bindService(ComponentImpl.java:624)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.access$400(ComponentImpl.java:52)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl$7.run(ComponentImpl.java:181)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.access$000(SerialExecutor.java:33)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:50)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.execute(SerialExecutor.java:68)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.calculateStateChanges(ComponentImpl.java:231)
at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.start(ComponentImpl.java:399)
at org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager.add(DependencyManager.java:169)
at io.github.semr.proflr.impl.Activator.init(Activator.java:14)
at org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyActivatorBase.start(DependencyActivatorBase.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2146)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
at aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:378)
at aQute.launcher.Launcher.activate(Launcher.java:303)
at aQute.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:193)
at aQute.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:89)
```

I have Searched it and got `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` as a solution but when I insert it in my code it give `enumExpectedError`.
I think I am not using annotation properly How can I use it in my code.

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
@Override
public Profile add() {
    // read from file, convert it to user class
    Profile bean = null;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) // I am using it here but show enum expected error

        try {

            File json = new File("C:\\profile.json");
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(json);

            bean = mapper.readValue(is,Profile.class);
            return bean;

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation must be used on the class you are deserializing and on which you are willing to ignore the unknown fields:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Profile {
    // ...
}
```